# How to make both div's still appear in the same line,while the first one has a fixed width, and the other shrinks accordingly with the page?

Tags: html, css

```
 it is  container 
main {  
  max-width: 1000px;
}

main div {
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

First div with fixed width, I want it to remain same width all times.

```
main .first { 
  background: red;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;

}



main .second {
  background: green;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;

}
```

I want this to shrink accordingly when the page resizes and still be in the same line with the "first div"

Comment: Use **display:inline;** for both divs in your CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Since snippet display has small area so i turned width of main.first to 100px because , 70%+300px will not work for small screen. You either have to reduce percentage or pixels for small screens

```css
main {  
  max-width: 1000px;
}

main div {
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
main .first { 
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
display:inline-block;
}



main .second {
  background: green;
  width: 70%;
  float: left;
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<main>
<div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</main>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reliably do this one of two ways, both of which requiring CSS Level 3:

**Flexboxes**

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

main div {
  padding: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main .first {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
}

main .second {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</main>
```

**calc()**

```css
main {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

main div {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block; /* you can alternatively use float:left here */
  padding: 30px;
}

main .first {
  background-color: red;
  width: 300px;
}

main .second {
  background-color: green;
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="first"></div>
  <div class="second"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.